# How to have getElementsByClassName target all tagged elements - and is there a better alternative?

Tags: javascript, class, element, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm sorry, I think the answer to this will have been posted, but I've looked and I'm struggling to apply it.

I'm using this FitText non-library alternative posted by RobG (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15488590/1490943). It's great, but I want to apply it to a number of elements, not just one. I'm piecing together how to replace getElementById...

```
window.onload = function() {
  function doResize() {resize(document.getElementById('d0'), 5);}
  window.onresize = doResize;
  doResize();
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/cgwM4/)

... with getElementsByClassName...

```
window.onload = function() {
  function doResize() {resize(document.getElementsByClassName('d0')[0], 5);}
  window.onresize = doResize;
  doResize();
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/cgwM4/2/)

... but I can't figure out how to target *all* elements tagged with that class rather than just specific ones. And I'm wondering if there's an alternative that will work in earlier MSIE - a way of getting all with that class, without using ClassName.

I'm really sorry to be ignorant about this. It'll be obvious, but I don't know where to start... Thank you for having a look.

Comment: I'm sure I'll get heat for this, but I suggest just using jQuery and it's class selector, which is just `$('.class')`.

Comment: You won't get heat from me - I'm grateful you looked! But I'm trying to find an alternative to using libraries... thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @BradM Not a bad suggestion. Although this seems like a simple example, it would definitely help with event handlers (that the OP is using), as well as DOM querying (which the OP is using). And the OP seems to have a general understanding of how this all works, so taking it to the next level with jQuery could definitely help

Comment: The question is, *why* are you trying to find an alternative to using libraries? Heck, you are essentially just "cut and pasting" code from jQuery anyway. Yeah, it takes a few more milliseconds for your page to load, but the benefits are ridiculously good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is loop through them:

```
function doResize() {
    var qsa = document.querySelectorAll(".d0"), l = qsa.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) resize(qsa[i],5);
}
```

Note that I used `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName` - this enables support in IE8. If you really need older than that, you might want to use a `name` attribute instead, because even ancient IE supports `getElementsByName`.

Comment: I don't want to try your patience - but could you help me through using getElementsByName? Can I use that on divs or bodies of text?

Comment: You can use it on any element, just like `getElementsByClassName`, just with a different attribute. So like `<div name="resizeme">`. That said, I would advise against it since `name` attributes are generally reserved for form elements, and you shouldn't still be supporting IE7.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point. I'll use your solution - I really appreciate it!